# override grunt jshint config at the file level

Tags: gruntjs

Can the jshint grunt config be overridden at the file level? For instance, there is a file in which I would like bitwise operators to be allowed. I thought adding the comment below to the top of the file would cause it to pass, but it still failed.

/* jshint bitwise:false */

Answer (score 4):

There should be no space before jshint.

```
/*jshint bitwise:false */
```